# Knapsack Problem: Find Top-K Lower Profit Solutions

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems, backtracking

In the classic 0-1 knapsack problem, I am using the following (dynamic programming) algorithm to construct a "dp table":

```
def knapsack(weights, values, capacity, n):
    n = len(weights)
    weights = np.concatenate(([0], weights))  # Prepend a zero
    values = np.concatenate(([0], values))    # Prepend a zero
    
    table = np.zeros((n+1, capacity+1), dtype=np.int64)  # The first row/column are zeros
    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(capacity+1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0:
                table[i, w] = 0
            elif weights[i] <= w:
                table[i, w] = max(
                    table[i-1, w-weights[i]] + values[i],
                    table[i-1, w]
                )
            else:
                table[i, w] = table[i-1, w]
    return table
```

Then, by traversing the table using the following code, I am then able identify the items that make up the optimal solution:

```
def get_items(weights, capacity, table):
    items = []
    i = len(weights)
    j = capacity
    weights = np.concatenate(([0], weights))  # Prepend a zero
    table_copy = table.copy()
    while i > 0 and j > 0:
        if table_copy[i, j] == table_copy[i-1, j]:
            pass  # Item is excluded
        else:
            items.append(i-1)  # Item is included, fix shifted index due to prepending zero
            j = j - weights[i]
        i = i-1
    return items
```

This is great for finding the items that make up the single optimal solution (i.e., highest total summed value). However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve, say, the top-3 or top-5 solutions from this table that has a total weight that is less than or equal to the maximum capacity.

For example, the top-3 solutions for the following input would be:

```
weights = [1,  2,  3, 2, 2]
values =  [6, 10, 12, 6, 5]
capacity = 5

# with corresponding "dp table"
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 16, 16],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 18, 22],
       [ 0,  6, 10, 16, 18, 22]])
```

| Total Summed Value | Items (Zero-based Index) |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 1, 2 |
| 22 | 0, 1, 3 |
| 21 | 0, 1, 4 |

Note that there is a tie for both first place and so we'd truncate the solutions after the first 3 rows (though, getting all ties is preferred if possible). Is there an efficient way to obtain the top-k solutions from the "dp table" via some sort of backtracking process?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming algorithms can often be viewed as a shortest-paths problem on a suitable dag.  Then, if you only want the top-1 solution, i.e., the shortest path, you can use prev pointers to find the shortest path.  If you want the top-$k$ solutions, you can use any algorithm for finding the $k$ shortest paths in a graph.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7208720/781723.

In your code, you have

```
table[i, w] = max(
                    table[i-1, w-weights[i]] + values[i],
                    table[i-1, w]
                )
```

You can think of this as corresponding to a dag where each pair $(i,w)$ corresponds to a vertex in the dag, and I suspect the above expression means that you have an edge from $(i-1,w)$ to $(i,w)$ of length 0 and an edge from $(i-1,w-\text{weights}[i])$ to $(i,w)$ of length $-\text{values}[i]$.  (Why negation?  To convert the "max" to a "min".)  I'll let you work out the details of how your algorithm can be expressed as a problem of finding a shortest path in a dag.